# Navigation bar stays hidden

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am create a simple navigation bar that runs along the top of the screen but when the display is under 768px it displays as a menu that can be closed with a click of a X or opened by click the Hamburger button.

I also have the site hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/Tomas5786/TestSite/) and the page can be loaded via [here](https://tomas5786.github.io/TestSite/)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you should provide snippet code when answer. If you don't share its hard to identify the problem.

Secondly problem with your code is a spalling mistake. instead of `menu.addEventListner` use `menu.addEventListener`. You can find these Errors easily if see the console in your browser.